# How can I use a non-amplified mic on a MBP?

Tags: microphone, recording

How do I use a non-amplified/powered mic on a MBP? Or is it not possible without an amplifier/interface. I don't really want to get an amplifier or USB/Firewire interface, but if I have to, I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get good results with an unpowered microphone without a cable adapter or USB interface. The best bet is to purchase one of the many USB to audio interface dongles available. A favorite of mine is [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=103&cp_id=10311&cs_id=1031105&p_id=2881&seq=1&format=4#feedback) from Monoprice in California, which costs under $10. It includes a stereo headphone output and a mono mic input. It will also handle  powered microphones, such as the [Audio-Technica ATR-3350 lavaliere mic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HJ9PTO). I have two of these mics, and they offer excellent value for money (about $20).

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I will end up with one of those lavalier mics. Awesome price!